# How to write a raw hex byte to stdout in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

How do you get Python 3 to output raw hexadecimal byte? I want to output the hex `0xAA`.

If I use `print(0xAA)`, I get the ASCII '170'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to first create a `bytes` object:

```
x = bytes.fromhex('AA')
```

And then output this to `stdout` using the buffered writer

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(x)
```

Comment: You can also use the byte prefix (`b`). For example: `sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x90'*100)`.

Answer (score 20):

`print()` takes *unicode text* and encodes that to an encoding suitable for your terminal.

If you want to write raw bytes, you'll have to write to `sys.stdout.buffer` to bypass the [`io.TextIOBase` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) and avoid the encoding step, and use a `bytes()` object to produce bytes from integers:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes([0xAA]))
```

This won't include a newline (which is normally added when using `print()`).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the hex-byte escape sequence ("\x") in a bytestring, specifying the `sys.stdout.buffer.write()` method:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\x74\x68\x65\x73\x65\x20\x61\x72\x65\x20\x72\x61\x77\x20\x62\x79\x74\x65\x73\x21\xde\xad\xbe\xef")'
```

will output on your terminal:

```
these are raw bytes!ޭ��%
```

and inspecting with `xxd`:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\x74\x68\x65\x73\x65\x20\x61\x72\x65\x20\x72\x61\x77\x20\x62\x79\x74\x65\x73\x21\xde\xad\xbe\xef")' | xxd
00000000: 7468 6573 6520 6172 6520 7261 7720 6279  these are raw by
00000010: 7465 7321 dead beef                      tes!....
```