# Python 2.7 write raw bytes to stdout

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, hex, byte

I need to write 4 raw hex bytes to bash by using a Python 2.7 script. I've bumped into this thread that seemed promising: 
[How to write a raw hex byte to stdout in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917595/how-to-write-a-raw-hex-byte-to-stdout-in-python-3)  -  but it only applied to Python 3. 
What's the equivalent of that method in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [binascii.unhexlify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
import sys
from binascii import unhexlify as unhex

# Prints out the character 'N' 
sys.stdout.write(unhex('4e'))

# ...

# Prints out Hello, world!
sys.stdout.write(''.join(map(unhex, [
                     '48', '65', '6c', 
                     '6c', '6f', '2c', 
                     '20', '77', '6f', 
                     '72', '6c', '64', 
                     '21'
                ])))
```

Comment: Yeah but this way I still print the characters in a Unicode string, I need to directly write the bytes without encoding..is that even possible? What I'm ultimately aiming to do is overwriting a 4 bytes canary via buffer overflow.