# Convert hex string to characters in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I need to convert a string such as `5555555547aa` into a string of characters (that one would be `�GUUUU`). I have a function working in python2 which is posted below, but I can't get anything to work right in python3. How would I do this?

```py
    def hex_conv(hex_str):
      arr = [hex_str[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex_str), 2)]
      rev = arr[::-1]
      out_str = ""
      for i in rev:
        print(i)
        out_str += ("\\x" + i).decode("string_escape")
      return out_str
```

More Clearly of what I need outputted (in Python2):

```py
print('\xaa\x47\x55\x55\x55\x55')
```

I have tried

```py
print(bytes.fromhex("5555555547aa")[::-1].decode("utf-8", errors="replace"))
```

which doesn't quite work. It appears to produce the same output but the actual bytes are different.

Note: The output of this is going to be piped into another program (for binary exploitation) so the bytes need to be printed exact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hexadecimal string to byte array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python)

Comment: Not quite. That just converts it to a byte array which still has \xaa as itself as opposed to �.

Comment: then do `.decode("utf8", errors="replace")` if you want a regular str with the error chars.

Comment: That's seems really close but it's quite correct. That seems to produce the hex 0x5555555547bdbfef when I need 0x5555555547aa

Comment: Wait, binexp? Just keep it as a bytestring, you can send bytestrings to subprocess or pwntools or whatever you're using.

Comment: Or if you're outputting to stdout, use [sys.stdout.buffer.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917595/how-to-write-a-raw-hex-byte-to-stdout-in-python-3) instead

Comment: The second one worked! Feel free to make an actual answer and I'll go accept it. I'm planning on learning pwntools soon but sys.stdout.buffer.write will suffice for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combine 2 steps: convert from hex to a bytestring with `bytes.fromhex`, and to print a bytestring to stdout using `sys.stdout.buffer.write`. Putting it all together:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes.fromhex("5555555547aa")[::-1])
```

Sourced from [hexadecimal string to byte array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python) and [How to write a raw hex byte to stdout in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917595/how-to-write-a-raw-hex-byte-to-stdout-in-python-3)